# How to get all rows from TableA based on specific id from TableB in pivot table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have 3 models: User, Post and Comment.
The relationships are set up like so:

User Model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Post Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Comment Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

And there is the `comment_post` pivot table (Which does not have a pivot Model - Do I need it in my case?)

Given a `post_id`, how can I get all the comments that belongs to it in the pivot table, for example:

```
comment_id | post_id
-----------|--------
     1     |   1
     2     |   2
     3     |   3
     4     |   4
     5     |   1
```

If I want to get all the comments that belong to post with `post_id` `1`, which would result in comments `1` and `5` - how can I achieve that? Nothing I tried work.

I've tried adding `withPivot` to the relationship, and then `wherePivot` to the query, tried defining the `post_id` and `comment_id` explicitly in the relationship, for example:

```
$comments = Comment::with(['posts' => function ($query) use ($comment_id) {
    $query->wherePivot('post_id', $post_id);
}])->get();
```

It just doesn't work.

I either get all the comments, or I get `Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't trouble yourself with not needed complexity. Simply use your defined relationships to do so:

```
Post::find(1)->comments;
```

And you don't need a model for your pivot table in this case.

You can't access pivot table with `wherePivot` in the query. I don't have any specific idea about the way you're trying to do the job. But mainly, you have to specify your desired data. If you want the comments of 'a' post, you have to find the post and get the comments related to that post. Your way is getting all the comments and their posts and check if the id of the post is the same as your desired `post_id`. This way is too complicated and have redundunt data and can be logically incorrect.

Comment: Oh wow, looks so simple! I edited the post so that you can see how I tried to do (added an example query) - I tried doing it from "the other way" via the `File` model but now I am not sure if that's even possible - do you think it would be possible to achieve your query but similar to what I tried to do?